# Unable to locate MicrosoftAppId/Password settings in Azure Bot

Tags: azure, botframework

this past summer, when I created a Bot in Azure and wanted to get the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword settings, I could open up the Application settings tab on the bot page and scroll down and both would be there. Now, I create a bot and do the same thing but neither setting is there anymore. Where did they go?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a difference between v3 and v4 bots. The settings are there if you create a V3 bot.

Answer (score 0):

The V4 SDK uses the BotFile and BotSecret in the application settings in the app service. The AppId and the Password are supposed to be securely encrypted in the .bot file. But in case you wish to get the AppId and Password, please refer to the steps in [Find Your Azure Bot’s AppID and AppSecret](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/03/find-your-azure-bots-appid-and-appsecret/)